# Angular dynamic components. How to add projectable nodes with parent component injector?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-dynamic-components

I create dynamic component:

```
const comp = createComponent(componentType,
            {
                environmentInjector: this.appRef.injector,
                elementInjector: parentComponentInjector,
            }
        );
```

I can add `projectableNodes` like this:

```
const comp = createComponent(componentType,
                {
                    environmentInjector: this.appRef.injector,
                    projectableNodes: [...childCompnents]
                }
            );
```

That way I can add `projectableNodes` but the problem is that I need to create `childComponents` before I `parentComponent`. Therefore I cannot inject them with `parentComponentInjector` and I cannot take adventage of chierachical DI Angular has, beacuse to get the `parentInjector` I need to create `parentComponent` before `childComponents`.
Is there a way I can use both `projectableNode` and Angular DI?

Comment: what's the Angular version you're using?

Comment: I am using angular 15. But it look like it is an open issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/51421